# How to use $_Get to store its values in a database?

Tags: php, mysql, get

I want to display all users that a "super" user is responsible for. Then the "super" user can send a comment to any of the users by clicking on their user id.

The first part of showing all the users is working fine! My problem is in sending a comment by the super user. I want to store the user id (ie `suid`) in the database. So I think to use the `$_Get` function. But when I tried it, nothing stores in the database. I think I made a mistake in it. So can anyone help me on that?

This is the code that will show all users to the super user:

```
    <?php

session_start();?>
<?php
require("noCache.php");
$uid=$_SESSION['uid'];

?>
<html>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<title>Send a comment</title>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/reset.css" type="text/css" media="all">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/layout.css" type="text/css" media="all">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css" type="text/css" media="all">
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.4.2.js" ></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/cufon-yui.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/cufon-replace.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/Myriad_Pro_400.font.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/Myriad_Pro_700.font.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/Myriad_Pro_600.font.js"></script>
</head>


<body>
<div class="main">

    <header>
        <div class="wrapper">
            <h1><a href="index.php" id="logo"> Biz</a></h1>

        </div>
        <nav>
            <ul id="menu">
                <li class="alpha"><a href="index.php"><span><span>Home</span></span></a></li>
                <li><a href="About.html"><span><span>About</span></span> </a></li>
                <li><a href="Projects.html"><span><span>Projects</span></span></a></li>
                <li><a href="Contacts.php"><span><span>Contacts</span></span></a></li>
                <li class="omega"><a href="Services.html"><span><span>Services</span></span></a></li>
            </ul>
        </nav>
        </br></br>

</header>


<head>
<!-- CSS Stylesheet -->
<style type="text/css">
html{

}
body{
    text-align:center;

}

</style>
</head>
<?php
$dbh=mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "hahaha1") or die (mysql_error());
mysql_select_db ("senior");
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM sensorusers where uid=$uid");
echo "<html><body>";
echo "<table cellspacing=10 cellpadding=5 ><tr> <th>ID</th><th>Name</th><th>Username</th><th>Password</th><th>Date of Registeration</th><th>Phone</th></tr>";
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
{   echo "<form method='post' action='sendcomment.php'>";
    echo "<tr><td><input type='submit' name='suid' value='".$row['suid']."' /></td>";
    echo "<td>" . $row['name'] . "</td>";
    echo "<td>" . $row['dusername'] . "</td>";
    echo "<td>" . $row['password'] . "</td>";
    echo "<td>" . $row['date'] . "</td>";
    echo "<td>" . $row['phone'] . "</td></tr></form>";
    $_GET['suid'] = $row['suid'];
}

echo "</table></body></html>";
mysql_close($dbh);
?>
<html>
<body>
<!-- CSS Stylesheet -->
<style type="text/css">

body {

    font-family:"Andalus"
    font: 16px ;
    color:black;
    padding: 30px 5px;
    text-align: center;
}

</style></body></html>
```

Here is the part that I want to ask about:

```
echo "<table cellspacing=10 cellpadding=5 ><tr> <th>ID</th><th>Name</th><th>Username</th><th>Password</th><th>Date of Registeration</th><th>Phone</th></tr>";
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
{   echo "<form method='post' action='sendcomment.php'>";
    echo "<tr><td><input type='submit' name='suid' value='".$row['suid']."' /></td>";
    echo "<td>" . $row['name'] . "</td>";
    echo "<td>" . $row['dusername'] . "</td>";
    echo "<td>" . $row['password'] . "</td>";
    echo "<td>" . $row['date'] . "</td>";
    echo "<td>" . $row['phone'] . "</td></tr></form>";
    $_GET['suid'] = $row['suid'];
}
```

**Solution:**

Thank you all for helping. I fixed the code. I used method `post` to save the value of `suid` the first time. Then I print it as a hidden input. Finally I save the value of the hidden input in the sql and it works!

Comment: Please post only code relevant to your question.

Comment: Is your `suid` and `uid` in the table if type int?

Comment: yes they are both integers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have `POST` I DONT SEE `GET`in your code , and its depend on your html inputs (u didnt post them)if u make method GET or POST.
if your method is GET then you use GET

but try use this

```
     if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
```

instead of

```
   if($submit){
```

EDIT .

you are using `method='post'`
then you must use `POST` not `GET`

EDIT2:
you have an error in your sql , you used `VALUE` and it should be `VALUES`

instead of this

```
 $place="INSERT INTO comments VALUE
```

replace it by

```
 $place="INSERT INTO comments (columns here ,..., ,..) VALUES
```

Comment: `$submit= $_POST['submit'];`   `submit` variable is set through `$_POST` so really, to actually use what the OP is trying `if (isset($submit)){ ... }`

Comment: i used post but it wasn't asved suid in the database :(

Comment: thhhhank u for ur helping i fixed the code.. i used post method to save value of sid at ther first time, then i print it as a hidden input, then save the value of the hidden input in the sql! thank u very much

Comment: nice that it helps you :) , make sure to accept this answer , good luck with the other codes

Comment: no its help, because u told me to use the post method thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

How to use `$_GET`: 
Put the data in the URL like so:

```
sendcomment.php?suid=blahblahblah
```

Then you can use `$_GET`, like so:

```
$suid = $_GET['suid']
```

Currently your code uses `POST` to send `suid`

Or change your form method.

---

```
echo "<form method='post' action='sendcomment.php?suid=".$row['suid']."'>";
```

Answer (score 1):

There are multiple issues in your code. I will try to list the biggest ones, but may still miss some.

**Code 1 -**
*Issue 1-*
You have multiple `<html></html>`,`<head></head>`, and `<body></body>` blocks.

```
<html>
...
<head>
...
</head>
<body>
...
<head>
...
</head>
...
echo "<html><body>";
...
echo "...</body></html>";
...
<html>
<body>
...
</body>
</html>
```

*Issue 2-*
Your `<form>` is around a `<td>` block, which is invalid, so it will not `POST` properly. It either needs to be around the table `<form><table></table></form>`, or inside a cell `<td><form></form></td>`.

```
echo "<table cellspacing=10 cellpadding=5 ><tr> <th>ID</th><th>Name</th><th>Username</th><th>Password</th><th>Date of Registeration</th><th>Phone</th></tr>";
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
{   echo "<form method='post' action='sendcomment.php'>";
    echo "<tr><td><input type='submit' name='suid' value='".$row['suid']."' /></td>";
    echo "<td>" . $row['name'] . "</td>";
    echo "<td>" . $row['dusername'] . "</td>";
    echo "<td>" . $row['password'] . "</td>";
    echo "<td>" . $row['date'] . "</td>";
    echo "<td>" . $row['phone'] . "</td></tr></form>";
    $_GET['suid'] = $row['suid'];
}

echo "</table></body></html>";
```

*Issue 3-*
You are misusing `$_GET` and it is outside your `<form></form>` tags. `$_GET` is used to get value from the `url`.

```
$_GET['suid'] = $row['suid'];
```

**Code 2-**
*Issue 1-*
You are setting `$id1=$_GET["suid"];`, but in your form in Code #1, you are using `method="post"`.

```
$id1=$_GET["suid"];
```

*Issue 2-*
When you are posting from Code #1 to Code #2 (`<form><input type='submit' name='suid' value='".$row['suid']."' /></form>`), you are only sending `name='suid'`, so all your `$_GET` & `$_POST` vars will not be set to be used in the `INSERT`-

```
$id1=$_GET["suid"];
...
$name=$_POST['sent_by'];
$id=$_POST['hidden_id'];
$id2=$_POST['hidden_id2'];
$message=$_POST['message'];
$submit= $_POST['submit'];
...
```

*Issue 3-*
You have errors in you query. It should be `VALUES`, not `VALUE`, you should include the columns before `INSERT INTO comments (id,name,message,receiver,sender,date,time) VALUES ('','$name','$message','$id','$id1','$date','$time')

```
$place="INSERT INTO comments VALUE('','$name','$message','$id','$id1','$date','$time')";
$run = mysql_query("$place");
```

*Issue 4-*
All your `value=` in your form is missing the quotes `''` around the values.

```
<form action="sendcomment.php" method="post">
    <input type ='hidden' name='hidden_id' value = <?php print $uid; ?> >
    <input type ='hidden' name='hidden_id2' value = <?php print $id1; ?> >
    Name : <input type ='name' name='sent_by'  value = <?php print $username; ?>></br> 
     Message: <textarea name='message'></textarea></br> 
     <input type='submit' value='submit' name="submit" /></br>
</form>
```

I know that you have accepted an answer, but you have a lot of code issues to still address. Each of these will cause you issues with your form and inserting into your database. Plus they will cause you more issues.

Comment: really ur reply is useful, i made changes in my codes.. but i didn't understand this "When you are posting from Code #1 to Code #2 (<form><input type='submit' name='suid' value='".$row['suid']."' /></form>), you are only sending name='suid', so all your $_GET & $_POST vars will not be set to be used in the INSERT"

Comment: Your 1st file loop `while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))` creates a form to post to `sendcomment.php` - `<form method='post' action='sendcomment.php'>`. The only field in that form is `suid` - `<input type='submit' name='suid' value='".$row['suid']."' />`. On the 1st page load of `sendcomment.php` it will try to set your `$vars` - `$id1=$_GET["suid"]; $name=$_POST['sent_by']; $id=$_POST['hidden_id']; $id2=$_POST['hidden_id2']; $message=$_POST['message']; $submit= $_POST['submit'];`. You should put those & `if($submit){}` block inside an `if(isset($_POST['message'])){}` to verify if posted

Answer (score 0):

Just simply this

```
$id1=$_GET["suid"];
```

replace with

```
$id1=$_POST["suid"];
```

When using $_GET varible shuld be in the url.
When using $_POST variable isn't shown in url